# For loop with Pandas: how to improve the code?

Tags: python, pandas, api, parsing

I'm using an API to get data for stocks in an index. The API has a maximum request limit so I am parsing the data. In every pass I am appending the Pandas DataFrame returned by the API such that by the end I have a large data frame with the full index - which would not have been accepted in one request.

The below is correct:

```
 # number of iterations
no_of_stocks = len(Mnemonics)
iterations = math.ceil(no_of_stocks / 50) - 1

# first iteration
string_mnemonics = ', '.join(Mnemonics[0:50])
stocks = ds.get_data(tickers= string_mnemonics, fields=['P'], start = '-1Y', end = '-0d', freq = 'D')

for i in range(iterations):
    to_parse_mnemonics = Mnemonics[(i+1)*50 : (i+2)*50]
    string = ', '.join(to_parse_mnemonics)
    stocks_temp = ds.get_data(tickers= string, fields=['P'], start = '-1Y', end = '-0d', freq = 'D')
    stocks = pd.concat([stocks, stocks_temp], axis = 1)
```

This looks very janky to me. My question is: is there a way to have only one line of code making the requests. I think a do-while loop would work - or to define a flexible DataFrame which would be totally defined within the loop.

I am very much a novice in coding and Python.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there's a one-line solution for that, but I believe it could be simplified a bit.

```py
# number of iterations
no_of_stocks = len(Mnemonics)
iterations = math.ceil(no_of_stocks / 50)

stocks = []
for i in range(iterations):
    string = ', '.join(Mnemonics[i*50 : (i+1)*50])
    stocks.append(ds.get_data(tickers=string, fields=['P'], start='-1Y', end='-0d', freq = 'D'))
stocks = pd.concat(stocks, axis=1)
```

Also I think clearing the index would be a good idea while concatenating since the index before that doesn't have much use, so you can pass in `ignore_index=True` while calling `pd.concat`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that doesn't work. this defines stocks as a list.